# IE and Div heights

Tags: html, css

Site in question:

http://www.sedulity.tk/

Site using Chrome 19 dev:

[image]

---

Site using IE9:

[image]

as you can see on the homepage using IE it seems like it not recognizing the height of the DIV of each picture, whereas on chrome and firefox there is no issue.

I think this is probably my fault, won't blame IE for it...but I can't figure it out :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css folder there is a css file `ie7style.css` and it's being used for ie (I've tested in ie8) and it has a class (.item-image) that is

```
.item-image{
    height:142px;
}
```

Try to fix it or just remove it.

Css file:    `http://www.sedulity.tk/wp-content/themes/DeepFocus/css/ie7style.css`

See in this developer Tool screenshot I've removed the css entry `height:142px` from class (.item-image) from file `ie7style.css`

[image]

After that (`without .item-image{height:142px}` in file `ie7style.css`) see the page in ie8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try adding a height to the .item

CSS

```
#portfolio-items .item {
    height:500px;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block; width: 230px; height: 509px;` works better, no?

Comment: ? not sure.  I'm sure there is more then 1 way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna check [this article](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for a cross-browser inline-block that doesn't overlap. your case is most likely caused by the "baseline", where the next set of elements base their tops on the last elements' baseline (which would be somewhere in the middle of the element).